# mobx computed getter is never evaluated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

Thats my stackblitz/codepen: https://stackblitz.com/edit/svgtest?file=MountingViewModel.tsx

```
 import { observable, computed } from 'mobx';

export class MountingViewModel  
{
  constructor(isSelected: boolean, id: string, callback: (mounting: string) => any)
  {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
    this.id = id;
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  @observable public isSelected: boolean;
  public id: string;
  public callback: Function;

  @computed get opacity() : number
  {
    console.log(this.isSelected);
    return this.isSelected ? 0.2 : 1.0;
  }
}
```

the getter opacity() is never hit when I click the red/blue rectanges.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because you are spreading the instances e.g. `<Roof {...this.allMountings.find(x => x.id === "roof") } />`

Spread does not invoke getters:

```
class Foo { 
  x = 123;
  get y() {
    return 456
  }
}

console.log({ ...new Foo() }); // {x:123} NO `y`
```